# A bootloader that I am making doesn't get any IRQ12

Tags: mouse, x86-64, bootloader, osdev, irq

The computer in which I test my operating system is a laptop with a touchpad. When I power the computer on, it reads the keyboard, but after I touch the touchpad, it doesn't read the touchpad nor the keyboard either.
And I also use qemu and on qemu it doesn't read the mouse but keeps reading the keyboard.

This is the code that I use for the mouse:

```
#ifndef _MOUSE
#define _MOUSE

#include "base.cpp"
#include "math.cpp"
#include "vector.cpp"
//#include "console.cpp"//------

class Mouse
{
    public:
    Bool key_pressed[3];
    Vector2 position;

    private:
    Vector<Ubyte> bytes_buffer;
    double mouse_area_y_respect_x;

    void limit_inside_area()
    {
        limit_inside(position.x,0,1);
        limit_inside(position.y,0,mouse_area_y_respect_x);
    }
    Bool process_stroke()
    {
        if(bytes_buffer.size()<4) return false;
        else
        {
            position.x=0;
            limit_inside_area();

            bytes_buffer.resize(bytes_buffer.size()-4);

            return true;
        }
    }

    Ubyte in_port_0x64()
    {
        Ubyte val;
        asm("in al,0x64;":"=a"(val));
        return val;
    }
    Ubyte in_port_0x60()
    {
        Ubyte val;
        asm("in al,0x60;":"=a"(val));
        return val;
    }
    void out_port_0x60(Ubyte byte)
    {
        asm("out 0x60,%%al"::"a"(byte));
    }
    void out_port_0x64(Ubyte byte)
    {
        asm("out 0x64,%%al"::"a"(byte));
    }
    void wait_for_device(Uint64 mode)
    {
        if(mode==0)
        {
            for(Uint64 n=0;n<10000;n++)
            {
                Ubyte val=in_port_0x64();
                if((val&1)==1) break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(Uint64 n=0;n<10000;n++)
            {
                Ubyte val=in_port_0x64();
                if((val&2)==0) break;
            }
        }
    }
    void send_to_device(Ubyte byte)
    {
        wait_for_device(1);
        out_port_0x64(0xD4);
        wait_for_device(1);
        out_port_0x60(byte);
    }
    Ubyte wait_for_device_acknowledge()
    {
        wait_for_device(0);
        return in_port_0x60();
    }

    public:


    void initialize(double _mouse_area_y_respect_x)
    {
        for(Uint64 n=0;n<3;n++)
        {
            key_pressed[n]=false;
        }
        mouse_area_y_respect_x=_mouse_area_y_respect_x;
        if(mouse_area_y_respect_x>=0.1 && mouse_area_y_respect_x<=100){}
        else if(mouse_area_y_respect_x<0.1) mouse_area_y_respect_x=0.1;
        else if(mouse_area_y_respect_x>100) mouse_area_y_respect_x=100;
        else
        {
            mouse_area_y_respect_x=1;
        }
        position=Vector2(0.5,mouse_area_y_respect_x/2);
    }
    void initialize_device()
    {
        asm("cli");

        wait_for_device(1);
        out_port_0x64(0xA8);
        wait_for_device_acknowledge();

        wait_for_device(1);
        out_port_0x64(0x20);
        wait_for_device(0);
        Ubyte status=in_port_0x60();
        status=status|2;
        wait_for_device(1);
        out_port_0x64(0x60);
        wait_for_device(1);
        out_port_0x60(status);

        send_to_device(0xF6);
        wait_for_device_acknowledge();

        send_to_device(0xF4);
        wait_for_device_acknowledge();

        asm("sti");
    }
    void update_from_interrupt()
    {
        Ubyte data=in_port_0x60();
        input_byte[input_byte_cycle]=data;
        input_byte_cycle++;
        if(input_byte_cycle>3)
        {
            input_byte_cycle=0;

            position.x=0;
        }
        position.x=0;

        //bytes_buffer.push_back(data);
        //if(bytes_buffer.size()>10000) bytes_buffer.resize(0);
    }
    Ubyte input_byte[4];
    Uint64 input_byte_cycle=0;
    void update()
    {




        //while(bytes_buffer.size()>0 && process_stroke()){}
    }
};

static Mouse*CURRENT_MOUSE;

#endif
```

This is the point where I call the function "initialize_device()" in the bootloader:

```
    Mouse mouse;
    mouse.initialize(768.0/1024);
    mouse.initialize_device();
    CURRENT_MOUSE=&mouse;

    set_interrupts_handler((Uint64)&interrupts_handler);

    //the BIOS call for VESA
    call_assembly(0,0x4f02,VESA_MODE,0,0,0,0,0,0x10);

    Uint64 time=0;
    while(1)
    {
        for(Uint64 n=0;n<1;n++)
        {
            CURRENT_KEYBOARD->update();
            CURRENT_MOUSE->update();
        }

        time++;
        console.draw(screen,time/10);

        screen.circlefill((CURRENT_MOUSE->position*1024).toPos(),10,0xffffff);

        if(bootloader_info.VESA->BitsPerPixel==24) screen.draw(bootloader_info.VESA->PhysBasePtr);
        else screen.draw_alpha(bootloader_info.VESA->PhysBasePtr);
    }
```

And the interrupt handler which handles some of the interrupts:

```
void interrupts_handler()
{
    Uint64 interrupt_number=get_interrupt_number_interrupts_handler();

    if(interrupt_number==8)
    {
        TIME++;
    }
    else
    {
        CURRENT_CONSOLE->printhex(interrupt_number);//---------------------
        CURRENT_CONSOLE->printf(" ");

        if(interrupt_number==9)
        {
            Uint64 var;
            asm("in al,0x60;"
                /*"out 0x61,al;"*/:"=a"(var));
            Ubyte keycode=var;
            CURRENT_KEYBOARD->update_from_interrupt(var);
        }
        else if(interrupt_number==0x74)
        {
            CURRENT_MOUSE->update_from_interrupt();
        }
        else if(interrupt_number==0x0f)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is only a small part of the code, but I have put what I think it's most important.

And the types (defined in base.cpp):

```
typedef char Int8;
typedef unsigned char Uint8;
typedef short int Int16;
typedef unsigned short int Uint16;
typedef int Int32;
typedef unsigned int Uint32;
typedef long long int Int64;
typedef unsigned long long int Uint64;

typedef Int8 Byte;
typedef Uint8 Ubyte;
typedef Ubyte* Ptr;
typedef Ubyte Bool;
```

With "CURRENT_CONSOLE->printhex(interrupt_number);" in the interrupt handler, I have made it print the numbers of the interrupts it gets, that's how I know that I don't get any IRQ12, (I have not remapped the PIC).

The other part of the interrupt handler, which is in nasm assembly:

```
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER:

%macro LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E 1
push rax
mov al,%1
jmp .handler
%endmacro

%macro LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 1
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x00
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x01
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x02
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x03
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x04
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x05
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x06
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x07
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x08
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x09
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0A
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0B
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0C
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0D
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0E
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0F
%endmacro

LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x00
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x10
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x20
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x30
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x40
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x50
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x60
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x70
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x80
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x90
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xA0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xB0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xC0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xD0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xE0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xF0

.handler:

cmp al,8
je .timer_or_double_fault
cmp al,9
je .keyboard
cmp al,0x0d
je .general_protection_fault
cmp al,0x0e
je .page_fault_or_floppy_disc
cmp al,0x0f
je .strange_or_spurious
cmp al,0x74
je .mouse


call NOT_HANDLED_INTERRUPT_MESSAGE
jmp $

.timer_or_double_fault:

;pop rbx
;pop rcx
;cmp rcx,0
;je .double_fault
;push rcx
;push rbx

push rbx
push rcx
mov rcx,[rsp-3]
mov rbx,[rsp-4]
cmp rcx,0
je .double_fault
pop rcx
pop rbx

jmp .timer

.keyboard:
.mouse:
.strange_or_spurious:
.timer:

push rbx
mov rbx,[POINTER_TO_INTERRUPTS_HANDLER]
cmp rbx,0
je .no_cpp

mov [INTERRUPT_NUMBER_FOR_HANDLER],al
PUSHA64
call [POINTER_TO_INTERRUPTS_HANDLER]
POPA64

.no_cpp:
pop rbx

mov al,0x20
out 0x20,al
jmp .end

.double_fault:
push rbx

call DOUBLE_FAULT_MESSAGE

BITS 64

.general_protection_fault:

call GENERAL_PROTECTION_FAULT_MESSAGE

mov al,0x20
out 0x20,al
jmp .end

.page_fault_or_floppy_disc:

push rbx
push rcx
mov rcx,[rsp-3]
mov rbx,[rsp-4]
cmp rcx,32
jl .page_fault
pop rcx
pop rbx

mov al,0x20
out 0x20,al
jmp .end

.page_fault:
push rbx


;-----------------------------

mov al,0x20
out 0x20,al
jmp .end

.end:
pop rax
iretq
```

**EDIT:**

I have changed the handler in assembly:

```
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER:

%macro LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E 1
push rax
mov al,%1
jmp .handler
%endmacro

%macro LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 1
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x00
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x01
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x02
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x03
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x04
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x05
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x06
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x07
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x08
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x09
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0A
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0B
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0C
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0D
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0E
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0F
%endmacro

LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x00
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x10
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x20
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x30
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x40
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x50
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x60
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x70
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x80
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x90
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xA0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xB0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xC0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xD0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xE0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xF0

.handler:

cmp al,8
je .timer_or_double_fault
cmp al,9
je .keyboard
cmp al,0x0d
je .general_protection_fault
cmp al,0x0e
je .page_fault_or_floppy_disc
cmp al,0x0f
je .strange_or_spurious
cmp al,0x74
je .mouse


call NOT_HANDLED_INTERRUPT_MESSAGE
jmp $

.timer_or_double_fault:

;pop rbx
;pop rcx
;cmp rcx,0
;je .double_fault
;push rcx
;push rbx

push rbx
push rcx
mov rcx,[rsp-3]
mov rbx,[rsp-4]
cmp rcx,0
je .double_fault
pop rcx
pop rbx

jmp .timer

.keyboard:
.mouse:
.strange_or_spurious:
.timer:

push rbx
mov rbx,[POINTER_TO_INTERRUPTS_HANDLER]
cmp rbx,0
je .no_cpp

mov [INTERRUPT_NUMBER_FOR_HANDLER],al
PUSHA64
call [POINTER_TO_INTERRUPTS_HANDLER]
POPA64

.no_cpp:

mov al,0x20
mov bl,[INTERRUPT_NUMBER_FOR_HANDLER]
cmp bl,0x70
jl .IRQ0_7
out 0xA0,al
.IRQ0_7:
out 0x20,al

pop rbx

jmp .end

.double_fault:
push rbx

call DOUBLE_FAULT_MESSAGE

BITS 64

.general_protection_fault:

call GENERAL_PROTECTION_FAULT_MESSAGE

jmp .end

.page_fault_or_floppy_disc:

push rbx
push rcx
mov rcx,[rsp-3]
mov rbx,[rsp-4]
cmp rcx,32
jl .page_fault
pop rcx
pop rbx

mov al,0x20
out 0x20,al
jmp .end

.page_fault:
push rbx


;-----------------------------

jmp .end

.end:
pop rax
iretq
```

**EDIT 2:**

Interrupt handler in assembly:

```
%macro PUSHA64 0
push rax
push rbx
push rcx
push rdx
push rsi
push rdi
push rbp
%endmacro

%macro POPA64 0
pop rbp
pop rdi
pop rsi
pop rdx
pop rcx
pop rbx
pop rax
%endmacro

LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER:

%macro LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E 1
push rax
mov al,%1
jmp .handler
%endmacro

%macro LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 1
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x00
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x01
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x02
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x03
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x04
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x05
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x06
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x07
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x08
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x09
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0A
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0B
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0C
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0D
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0E
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_E %1+0x0F
%endmacro

LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x00
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x10
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x20
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x30
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x40
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x50
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x60
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x70
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x80
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0x90
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xA0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xB0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xC0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xD0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xE0
LONG_MODE_BASIC_INTERRUPTION_HANDLER_16E 0xF0

.handler:

PUSHA64

cmp al,0x08
je .double_fault
cmp al,0x0d
je .general_protection_fault
cmp al,0x0e
je .page_fault
cmp al,0x70
je .timer
cmp al,0x71
je .keyboard
cmp al,0x76
je .floppy_disc
cmp al,0x7c
je .mouse
cmp al,0x77
je .strange_or_spurious

call NOT_HANDLED_INTERRUPT_MESSAGE
jmp $

.keyboard:
.mouse:
.strange_or_spurious:
.timer:
.floppy_disc:
mov rbx,[POINTER_TO_INTERRUPTS_HANDLER]
cmp rbx,0
je .no_cpp
mov [INTERRUPT_NUMBER_FOR_HANDLER],al
call [POINTER_TO_INTERRUPTS_HANDLER]
.no_cpp:
mov al,0x20
mov bl,[INTERRUPT_NUMBER_FOR_HANDLER]
cmp bl,0x78
jl .IRQ0_7
out 0xA0,al
.IRQ0_7:
out 0x20,al
jmp .end

.double_fault:
call DOUBLE_FAULT_MESSAGE
jmp .end_pop_error_code

.general_protection_fault:
call GENERAL_PROTECTION_FAULT_MESSAGE
jmp .end_pop_error_code

.page_fault:
jmp .end_pop_error_code

.end:
POPA64
pop rax
iretq

.end_pop_error_code:
POPA64
pop rax
pop qword[.void]
iretq

.void: dq 0
```

code that remaps the PICs:

```
BITS 32

io_wait:
push ecx
mov ecx,100
.loop:
loop .loop
pop ecx
ret

; Input:
; al: first PIC's offset
; bl: second PIC's offset
remap_PICs:

PIC1_COMMAND equ 0x20
PIC2_COMMAND equ 0xA0
PIC1_DATA equ 0x21
PIC2_DATA equ 0xA1
ICW1_INIT_WITH_ICW1_ICW4 equ 0x11
ICW4_8086 equ 0x01

mov ch,al
mov dh,bl

in al,PIC1_DATA
mov cl,al
in al,PIC2_DATA
mov dl,al

mov al,ICW1_INIT_WITH_ICW1_ICW4
out PIC1_COMMAND,al
call io_wait
out PIC2_COMMAND,al
call io_wait

mov al,ch
out PIC1_DATA,al
call io_wait
mov al,dh
out PIC2_DATA,al
call io_wait

mov al,4
out PIC1_DATA,al
call io_wait
mov al,2
out PIC2_DATA,al
call io_wait

mov al,ICW4_8086
out PIC1_DATA,al
call io_wait
out PIC2_DATA,al
call io_wait

mov al,cl
out PIC1_DATA,al
mov al,dl
out PIC2_DATA,al

ret
```

Comment: You should be sending End of Interrupts after handling CPU exceptions, only send them after handling external interrupts (IRQ0 to IRQ15). For IRQ0 to IRQ7 you do an EOI by sending 0x20 to port 0x20. For IRQ >= 8 you issue an EOI by sending 0x20 to port 0xA0 (to the slave PIC) and then a EOI to the master by sending 0x20 to port 0x20.

Comment: It also appears you are not remapping the PICs. By default IRQ0 to IRQ7 are mapped on top of the CPU exception (interrupt vector 0x08 to 0x0f). You will want to remap the primary PIC so that it doesn't overlap the CPU exceptions. I recommend reading this OSSDev article: https://wiki.osdev.org/8259_PIC

Comment: I have changed the code of the handler:

Comment: I made a typo I should have said "You should NOT be sending End of Interrupts after handling CPU exceptions"

Comment: I have put the new code on the question

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems:

1   you need to save all the registers (and restore them) at interrupt entry.   If you don’t do this, you cannot resume after the interrupt handler ran.   This is subtle to debug, because if you are idle before the interrupt, you won’t notice the corrupted register state.

2   you need to issue the ICWs to the PICs.   Somebody mentioned this in the comments, but without the ICWs, you really don’t know what the PIC is going to do with an interrupt.  Remap the interrupts to 0x20..0x30.

3   you need to choose how you interact with the PIC; the current vogue is to use the interrupt entry to both mask and acknowledge the interrupt, which frees other interrupts to occur.

4. you have intermingled your exceptions with interrupts.   This is problematic for two reasons: first you shouldn’t touch the PIC unless it is for a real interrupt; second some exceptions push an extra value on the stack which you need to accommodate.

So, save more registers, initialize the PICs, separate the exceptions from the interrupts.

Addendum to updated source:
1.   I don’t see any code where you initialized the PICs.
2.   That messed up assembler you are using is hiding way too much: if you have set the real interrupt base(s) to be 0x70 and 0x78, I expect to see code corresponding to these entries, and code which sets the corresponding IDT entries.   I see neither.

You have exhausted my patience; you haven’t provided the requested source and the source you have provided isn’t sensible.  I don’t see any way to help you.

Comment: I have now remapped the PICs to 0x70 and 0x78, and changed the code of the handler, but it still happens the same. I don't get any IRQ12.

Comment: Sure, put it up.

Comment: I have just put it

Comment: My bootloader switches sometimes between long mode and real mode in order to use BIOS functions like reading from the disc, and passes through 32-bit mode, where is where it remaps the PICs between the initial mapping (for the BIOS) and the mapping for my OS